# При переносе сайта на другой домен перестала работать Header(Location)

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.
Возникла довольно странная проблема. при переносе сайта на другой домен перестала работать header("Location: ....."); Подскажите как решить проблему.
Пример строк из кода: 
`header("Location: login.php");
exit();`
Заранее спасибо ;)

Comment: Спасибо uzumaxy за ответ.
Методом проб и ошибок смог определить, что header("Location: ..."); не работает после команды include '...';
Есть какой-нибудь способ решения такой головоломки?

Comment: А то, что инклудите случайно не содержит никакого вывода? Также иногда отсылке заголовков могут мешать сообщения об ошибках, выводимых в браузер

Comment: как именно функция перестала работать? пишет ошибку, если да - какую? 
иногда с nginx есть такая ерунда, когда require и header глючат.

Comment: еще файлики в utf-8 без BOM сохранить...

Answer (score 3):

Функцией header Вы даете команду на отправку заголовочной информации. Заголовочная информация должна предшествовать телу ответа.

Как только интерипритатор php встретит операцию вывода типа echo, то автоматически сгенерируются заголовки и начнется формирование тела ответа сервера. Все последующие вызовы функции не будут действительны, поскольку заголовочная информация уже сформирована.

Потому, скорее всего, проблема кроется в команде на вывод данных перед выполнением `header("Location: login.php");` Еще существует маленькая вероятность проблем на стороне хостинга.

**Решение**

- Убедитесь в наличии страницы login.php
- Создайте страницу [test.php](http://pastebin.com/teTDduaS) и разместите ее в необходимой директории

Если Вас перенаправит на страницу данного вопроса, то проблем с хостингом нету и нужно проверить код на наличие команд вывода данных перед `header("Location: login.php");`